# Communication with Turtlebot Roomba base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed all the stacks along with roomba_robot and serial_communication. Execute "MAKE" for all. I am trying to run this command:

rosrun roomba_500_series roomba560_node which throws below error:

turtlebot@ubuntu:~/myStacks$ rosrun roomba_500_series roomba560_node
[ INFO] [1362229508.730474686]: Roomba for ROS 2.01
[FATAL] [1362229508.869236551]: Could not connect to Roomba.
[FATAL] [1362229508.869597292]: BREAKPOINT HIT
file = /home/turtlebot/myStacks/roomba_robot/roomba_500_series/src/roomba560.cpp
line=156

Anyone please suggest if I am missing anything and help me in resolving this problem. It's urgent !! Thank You !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56808/communication-with-turtlebot-roomba-base/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-02**:
Error as below:turtlebot@ubuntu:~/myStacks$ rosrun roomba_500_series roomba560_node
[ INFO] [1362229508.730474686]: Roomba for ROS 2.01
[FATAL] [1362229508.869236551]: Could not connect to Roomba.
[FATAL] [1362229508.869597292]: BREAKPOINT HIT
file = /home/turtlebot/myStacks/roomba_robot/roomba_500

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-02**:
Could not connect to Roomba

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-03-02**:
Did u change the permission of usb port to which roomba is connected..

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-02**:
Nope. How will changing permission of USB port effect ? I mean I can see that it's detecting at /dev/ttyUSB0.. To what permission do I have to change ?

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-02**:
You mean shall I do this way:  chmod 777 <path to USB device which is /dev/ttyUSB0 here > ?

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-05**:
@Shade .. It's working now.. but many times after connection is established, it shows following messages and I am unable to communicate...[ERROR] [1362487447.570308487]: Could not retrieve sensor packets.  Please suggest.  Thanks.

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-05**:
It's getting disconnected as soon as connection is established..

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-03-05**:
Might need to add turtlebot to the group.  sudo usermod -a -G dialout turtlebot  --but I'm no expert.

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-06**:
Thanks.. Yup tried this one too. But it disconnects as soon as it's connected. Is there any way to achieve persistent connection ? Although it lists in /dev/ttyUSB* but connection is getting disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was issue with roomba 521 base's FTDI serial connection due to which it was getting disconnected as soon as it gets connected to roomba. I have tested on two other turtlebots that we have got in lab and everything working fine. Thanks for the help. Can you please accept this and close this as well as other questions that i raised. @shade

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1